# Effective time complexity for n bit addition and multiplication

Tags: time-complexity, cpu-architecture, multiplication, addition, alu

I have done a course on Computer Architecture and it was mentioned that on the most efficient processors with `n` bit architecture word size the addition/subtraction of two words has a time complexity of `O(log n)` while multiplication/division has a time complexity of `O(n)`.

If you do not consider any particular architecture word size the best time complexity of addition/subtraction is `O(n)` (https://www.academia.edu/42811225/Fast_Arithmetic_Speeding_up_Multiplication_Division_and_Addition_of_n_Bit_Numbers) and multiplication/division seems to be `O(n log n log log n)` (Strassen https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(log n) is the latency of addition if you can use n-bit wide parallel hardware with stuff like carry-select or carry-lookahead.

O(n) is the total amount of work that needs doing, and thus the time complexity with a fixed-width ALU for arbitrary bigint problems as n tends towards infinity.

---

For a multiply, there are n partial products in an n-bit multiply, so adding them all (with a Dadda tree for example) takes on the order of O(log n) gate delays of latency.  Integer addition is associative, so you can do that in parallel, e.g. `(a+b) + (c+d)` is 3 with the latency of 2, and it gets better from there.

Dadda trees can avoid some of the carry-propagation latency so I guess it avoids the extra factor of log n you'd get if you  you just used normal addition of each partial product separately.

See [Differences between Wallace Tree and Dadda Multipliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374925/differences-between-wallace-tree-and-dadda-multipliers) for more about practical considerations for huge Dadda trees.

Comment: I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374925/differences-between-wallace-tree-and-dadda-multipliers and now I am confused if with `n` bit architecture word size the multiplication/division of two words is possible with a time complexity of `O(log n)`. Is there any such actual hardware achieving this?

Comment: @zeitgeist: Oh right, I was half asleep when writing that earlier.  O(log n) sound right, or possibly `O( (log n)^2 )`.  As far as real hardware, no real CPU has a bit-width anywhere near infinity.  But modern high-performance x86 CPUs typically have a 64-bit multiply latency of 3 cycles, vs. an integer add latency of 1 cycle.  I don't know how many gate delays that is. I haven't checked the literature.  I find Alain's suggestion surprising, that modern architectures don't care much about latency; CPUs certainly do, especially for scalar integer.  They do also care about throughput, of course.